# add print and download protected pdf viewer to web site

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

Is there any way to add slide share like PDF viewer to the web site?

Only users can be able to `view` document... `print` or `download` can't be done.I tried several `JavaScript plugins` for doing that but unable to find one that has no print and downloadable options. And also client can disable JavaScript in browser therefore I think of that suitable server side script.

I also unable to find a server side script (PHP) for this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the file outside the web root directory because the web browser follows the local file system privileges and not its own. Put them into a directory with a .htaccess file that blocks all communication.
Ex: Order deny,allow
    deny from all

I don't know how much it will gonna help you.